# Creation of AppFlow via Lambda: Googleanalytics source error

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, google-analytics, amazon-appflow

I am trying to create an AppFlow via Lambda. I have already successfully created a connection to Google Analytics. However, for the actual flow itself, I encountered this error:

**"An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the CreateFlow operation: Create Flow request failed: Googleanalytics source connector does not support outputting custom file types"**

```
destinationFlowConfigList=[
{
 'connectorType': 'S3',
 'connectorProfileName': 'Test',
 'destinationConnectorProperties': {
   'S3': {
   'bucketName': 'test-bucket',
   's3OutputFormatConfig': {
     'fileType': 'JSON', #'CSV'|'JSON'|'PARQUET'
     'prefixConfig': {
       'prefixType': 'FILENAME', #'FILENAME'|'PATH'|'PATH_AND_FILENAME',
       'prefixFormat': 'MINUTE' #'YEAR'|'MONTH'|'DAY'|'HOUR'|'MINUTE'
     },
   'aggregationConfig': {
    'aggregationType': 'None' #'None'|'SingleFile'
   }
  }
 }
}
},
],
tasks=[
{
  "taskType": "Filter", #Arithmetic|Filter|Map|Mask|Merge|Truncate|Validate (For projection tasks, selected task type has to be filter)
  "sourceFields": [
  "ga:users|METRIC",
  "ga:newUsers|METRIC"
],
"connectorOperator": {
  "GoogleAnalytics": "PROJECTION"
}
}
```

I have tried changing s3OutputFormatConfig to different file types to no avail. Am I missing something? That's the only element that seems to dictate the file type. Also, documentations online haven't really been helpful. I'd appreciate any help, please. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Edit the config and **remove** the line:

```
     'fileType': 'JSON', #'CSV'|'JSON'|'PARQUET'
```